# OrientDB pyorient - Query JSON using Binary Protocol

Tags: orientdb

I want to use the binary protocol in pyorient (faster performance then HTTP).

I want to process JSON response though from query like below:

response = client.query("select @this.toJson('out_*:-1') from Worker where userName = '" + userName + "'")

However I get a JSON serialisation issue from the Pyorient library - is it possible (NOT using http API) to process JSON from query response using only binary protocol?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Which version are you using? Pyorient itself uses binary to work with orient. What issue are you getting? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am using community 2.2.10 of OrientDb, and the latest pyorient (pip installed just the other day).

Comment: Can you post full code and error that you are getting? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting an error from your query even trying it in Studio `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized JSON formatting option: out_*:-1`. Why do you need the output in JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

try this as your query:

```
response = client.query("select @this.toJson('fetchPlan:out_*:-1') from Worker where userName = '" + userName + "'")
```